# Phaser 3 Arcade Gravity Isn't working properly no matter what value i set it to

Tags: javascript, game-physics, game-development, phaser-framework

I'm working on a new project in phaser and for some reason the gravity in the game is all messed up, when i attempt to jump i jump like a centimeter. if i change the values nothing changes its always glitched. how can i make it so that i jump and fall normally?

I've had some previous projects and the gravity works just fine, for this project i am using the latest stable release of phaser 3. I honestly cant see what the error is and i've been at it for a while.

there was a lot of code that wasn't relevent to the error so i removed it to make it easier for someone to review this.

game.js

```
const socket = io();
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1000,
    height: 550,
    parent: 'master',
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 300 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: resources,
        create: mechanics,
        update: controls
    }
};
const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function resources() {
    this.load.image("arena", "../resources/images/arena1.png");
    this.load.image("floor", "../resources/images/floor.png");
    this.load.atlas("warrior", "../resources/images/characters/warrior.png","../resources/images/characters/warrior.json");


}
var warrior;

function mechanics() {

    grasslands = this.add.image(500, 225, "arena").setScale(0.7);


    warrior = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 490, "warrior").setScale(2).setSize(15, 15);
    
    floor = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    floor.create(500, 545, "floor").setVisible(false);

    this.physics.add.collider(warrior, floor);
    warrior.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    warrior.body.onWorldBounds = true;
}   




function controls() {
    
    key = this.input.keyboard.addKeys("W,A,S,D");


    if(key.A.isDown) {
        warrior.setVelocityX(-100);
        warrior.flipX = true;


    }else if (key.D.isDown) {
        warrior.setVelocityX(100);
        warrior.flipX = false;
    


    }else if (key.W.isDown && warrior.body.touching.down) {
        warrior.setVelocityY(-330);
    }else{
        warrior.setVelocity(0);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because of this line `warrior.setVelocity(0);`. This line, stops the gravity of working, as intended *(and hinders jumping)*, since on scene updates, the velocity is set to `0`. Remove **that** line and add `warrior.setVelocityX(0)` at the start of the `controls` function and everything should work fine *(if you want/have to keep the `if-else` block)*. ***Or check out my working demo at the end of this answer.***

```
function controls() {
    key = this.input.keyboard.addKeys("W,A,S,D");

    warrior.setVelocityX(0);

    if(key.A.isDown) {
        warrior.setVelocityX(-100);
        warrior.flipX = true;
    }else if (key.D.isDown) {
        warrior.setVelocityX(100);
        warrior.flipX = false;
    }else if (key.W.isDown && warrior.body.touching.down) {
        warrior.setVelocityY(-330);
    }
}
```

I would only stop the **left/right** movement, when the player stops pressing the keys *( with `setVelocityX(0)`)*, and let gravity take care of stopping the jump/upwards movement.

**Here a basic demo:**

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 160,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 200 },
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    }
}; 

var cursors;
var player;
var playerStateText;
const SPEED = 250;

var isJumping = true;

function create () {
    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Use arrow Keys to move!')
    
    let ground = this.add.rectangle(-40, 120, 480, 50, 0xBAF0FF).setOrigin(0);
    player = this.add.rectangle(20, 20, 30, 30, 0xcccccc).setOrigin(0);
    
    ground = this.physics.add.existing(ground);
    ground.body.setImmovable(true);
    ground.body.allowGravity = false;
    
    player = this.physics.add.existing(player);
    
    this.physics.add.collider(player, ground, _ => isJumping = false);      
}

function update (){
    
    if (cursors.left.isDown){
        player.body.setVelocityX(-SPEED);
    } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.body.setVelocityX(SPEED);
    }
    else {
        player.body.setVelocityX(0);
    }
    
    if (!isJumping && cursors.up.isDown){
        player.body.setVelocityY(-SPEED * .75);
        isJumping = true;
    } 
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```