# How to set up jump on collide in phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

#### the problem

I have been create a game with phaser.js but a cant set up the jump on collide

#### What i want

Basically, what I want is for the player to be unable to jump again if they collide with the ceiling or a wall, and only able to jump again when they collide with the floor.

#### what i have

when the player collide with the ceiling or wall him can jump again

#### My code

the player jumping code looks actually like that

```
const isPlayerFallingOrJumping = isCurrentState('fall') || isCurrentState('jump');

if (isPlayerFallingOrJumping) this.stateMachine.setState('idle');
```

Comment: check out the demo of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72443545/1679286), this should do what you want. You would have to change the variable checking to your state checking. I hope this helps and I didn't miss anything.

Comment: i read the code and I thinks it won't work, cause I use the same layer and tile seat to wall, floor and ceiling. I have been wondering to try to create a custom propertie to use on the floor tiles, do you think it is a good idea? and how can I set up collide using custom propertie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the the the tile index *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tile.html#index__anchor))* like in this example below. The example is loosly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72443545/1679286), but adding the whole tile logic into the mix.

**Here is a Demo:**
*You can jump from the floor, but not when touching the **red** wall.*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:10px;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536 / 5.2,
    height: 70,
    zoom: 2.5,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity: { y: 50 },
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    },
    banner: false
}; 

var cursors;
var player;
var playerStateText;
const SPEED = 50;

var isJumping = true;

function create () {
    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
    graphics.fillRect(8, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(16, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(24, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.generateTexture('tiles', 8*4, 8);

    let level = [
      [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    ];

    let map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 8, tileHeight: 8 });
    let tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    let layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);
    layer.setCollisionBetween(1,3);
    
    this.player = this.add.circle(16, 16, 6, 0xffffff)
        .setDepth(2);
    
    this.physics.add.existing(this.player);
    
    this.physics.add.collider(layer, this.player, function(player, tile){
        if(tile.index == 1 && player.body.blocked.down ){
          isJumping = false;
        }
    });
    
    this.keys = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update(){
  
  if(this.keys.left.isDown){
    this.player.body.setVelocityX(-SPEED);
  }else if(this.keys.right.isDown){
    this.player.body.setVelocityX(SPEED);
  } else {
    this.player.body.setVelocityX(0);
  }
  
  if (!isJumping && this.keys.up.isDown){
    this.player.body.setVelocityY(-SPEED * .75);
    isJumping = true;
  } 
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<span style="font-family: Arial;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
Use Arrow-Key to move the player</span><br>
```

> *I update my example to include `player.body.blocked.down`, so that if floor tiles are used for the wall, wall jumps are prevented.*

**For matter.js physics engine:**
With matter everything is abit more complicated, watch out things likefor ghost collisions, those can happen and would/should have to be dealt with, like in [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/tilemap/collision/matter-ghost-collisions). (because of that, and some other reasons, `arcade physics` is the prefered inital physics choice, **atleast for me**)

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:10px;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536 / 5.2,
    height: 70,
    zoom: 2.5,
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter:{debug:true},
    },
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    },
    banner: false
}; 

var cursors;
var player;
var playerStateText;
const SPEED = 3;

var isJumping = true;

function create () {
    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
    graphics.fillRect(8, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(16, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(24, 0, 8, 8);
    graphics.generateTexture('tiles', 8*4, 8);

    let level = [
      [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
      [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    ];

    let map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 8, tileHeight: 8 });
    let tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    let layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);
    layer.setCollisionBetween(1,3);
    
    this.matter.world.convertTilemapLayer(layer);
    
    // Mark the tiles
    layer.forEachTile(function (tile) {
        if (tile.index === 1 ){
            tile.physics.matterBody.body.label = 'floor';
        }
    });
       
    this.matter.world.on('collisionstart', function (event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < event.pairs.length; i++) {
            
                // check if marked tiles and player are colliding
                if(event.pairs[i].bodyA.label == 'floor'
                  && event.pairs[i].bodyB.label == 'player') {
                    isJumping = false;
                }
            }
     });
    
    this.player = this.add.circle(16, 16, 6, 0xffffff)
        .setDepth(2)
        .setOrigin(.5);

    // Mark the player
    this.matter.add.gameObject(this.player, {label:'player'});
    this.keys = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update(){
  
  if(this.keys.left.isDown){
    this.player.setVelocityX(-SPEED);
  }else if(this.keys.right.isDown){
    this.player.setVelocityX(SPEED);
  } else {
    this.player.setVelocityX(0);
  }
  
  if (!isJumping && this.keys.up.isDown){
    this.player.setVelocityY(-SPEED * .75);
    isJumping = true;
  } 
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<span style="font-family: Arial;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
Use Arrow-Key to move the player</span><br>
```

Comment: for some reason the `this.physics` return undefined, i don't now if it's important to say but i am using Matter.js.

Comment: @MatheusSantosAraújo I added a matter.Js example, to my answer. I hope this helps